# search/find a folder that has a name with integer numbers in linux from terminal

Tags: linux, search, command, find, locate

I am using fedora 15 on my machine. Actually i am trying to find the folders with name like `apache-tomcat-7.0.37` by searching in the entire file system

Actually i had some folders like below in the path `/opt/tomcat/`

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.37
apache-tomcat-6.0.34
apache-tomcat-7.0.67
.........
```

And some folders at `/usr/share/tomcat/`

```
apache-tomcat-4.0.7
apache-tomcat-6.0.4
apache-tomcat-8.0.6
.........
```

So i want is to locate/find/search all these folder paths from linux terminal by using a command.

I have googled a lot and got some commands like `locate` and `find` as below

```
find / -name apache-tomcat*
locate apache-tomcat
```

The above commands are listing all the folder including extra unwanted information of folders, so actually what i want is , need to search for only for the folders that has the name like `apache-tomcat-x.x.x,apache-tomcat-xx.xx.xx`

Here in the folder name the starting words `apache-tomcat` is same and only the integer part (`version number`) changes. So i want to find all the folders with different version number like by using regular expressions in place of integer numbers to find the folders

so can anyone please let me know how to search the folder of the above scenario by using a command with regular expressions or someting like that which find all the folders with name `apache-tomcat-xx.x.xxx`.....

Comment: Did you consider using the `locate` command then piping its output to some `grep` or `awk` ?

Comment: yup got some commands like locate apache-tomcat | grep -E .... but does n't worked so approached SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should find all files, diretories, links, etc. that have the pattern apache-tomcat-X.Y.Z where X, Y, and Z are integers.

```
find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/apache-tomcat-[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+"
```

If you're looking only for directories, use this variant:

```
find . -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/apache-tomcat-[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+"
```

If you want to search the entire system starting at /, use this variant:

```
find / -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/apache-tomcat-[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+"
```

Comment: I tried creating the same test directories in your original post and I was able to get the expected result. Which directory are you running this command from ? This command is going to search only under the current directory you're in.

Comment: no sorry actually as i indicated in the question i want to search in the entire file system for the folder of that format as fast as possible...

Comment: Added a third variant, which starts the search from /. Prefix the command with sudo if you run into permission issues.

Comment: yup that worked after replacing . with / in the above command, but actually i want to run this on linux server in order to check for tomcat installed or not, so actually "locate" command is very fast and getting the accurate result, so we need to run updatedb for sure in order to get the full results ?

Comment: Actually i am making a script that will execute the command and returns the paths actually

Comment: Yes I agree locate is faster. Usually the locatedb is updated once a day or such using a cron job on the system. Running updatedb ensures you get up to date results. For example try removing one of the directories and run locate immediately without updatedb, and you would still get the result for the directory you just removed.

Comment: k that means anyway the locatedb command will be updated once a day by default automatically by the system right ?

Comment: Actually as i told i am preparing a script(Using python) that executes the above command and get the results and perform some necessary operation on the result later. So when i executed the command in linux terminal its just displaying a ten lines of information, but when i execute it with python its displaying 1000 +lines of information that is its checking in all thousand paths when we used find.... but when we use locate the results are accurate ......

Comment: That just indicates that the command run from your python script is not the same you ran from the shell. Look for things like escaping the \ character in python. You need to use raw strings. More of this from python documentation here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a suitable regular expression to `locate` in order to do a fast search of your entire system:

```
locate -b --regex "apache-tomcat-[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$"
```

As with any use of `locate`, the file database it uses will need to be sufficiently up-to-date. If you have sufficient permissions, you can do `sudo updatedb` to force an update.

Comment: locate is going to retrieve files in all locations and not under one directory you're interested (if you are). Also locate only retrieves files from its database. So you need to run **sudo updatedb** prior to running locate to ensure your database is up to date. locate is admittedly faster than find usually.

Comment: @Tuxdude: Yep, agreed, there are definitely tradeoffs between find and locate, and which to use depends on the specific circumstances. I'll add something to my answer.